# MongoDB project function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I get stuck at creating a MongoDB query. I have five collections that all have a relationship with each other. See the photo with the database structure below.

*MongoDB Version: 4.2.3*

After a long thought, I came to this result with the query below.

```
{ 
    "$lookup" : { 
      "from" : "capcodes", 
      "localField" : "capcodes", 
      "foreignField" : "_id", 
      "as" : "ccr"
  }
},
{ 
  "$lookup" : { 
      "from" : "regios", 
      "localField" : "ccr.regio", 
      "foreignField" : "_id", 
      "as" : "regionaam"
  }
}, 
{ 
  "$lookup" : { 
      "from" : "disciplines", 
      "localField" : "ccr.discipline", 
      "foreignField" : "_id", 
      "as" : "DisciplineNaam"
  }
}, 
{ 
  "$lookup" : { 
      "from" : "gpkrs", 
      "localField" : "ccr.gpkr", 
      "foreignField" : "_id", 
      "as" : "gkprNaam"
  }
}
```

My output is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5e501008bb6f081a00aab18d",
    "capcodes": [
      "0900307",
      "0900350"
    ],
    "tijd": "2020-02-21T16:08:07.484Z",
    "melding": "BRANP 1 BGM-03 Reanimatie (Inzet AED) PARELGRASSTRAAT ARNHEM 073780",
    "device": "MACBOOK-VAN-SIMON",
    "__v": 0,
    "ccr": [
      {
        "_id": "0900307",
        "regio": "5dd5645d9c432c413ce3cfc1",
        "gpkr": "5dd5500f5f640af0afb9a23a",
        "functie": "ploegcommandant Arnhem",
        "__v": 0,
        "discipline": "5ddd10629ce8a5255458cf9b"
      },
      {
        "_id": "0900350",
        "regio": "5dd5645d9c432c413ce3cfc1",
        "gpkr": "5dd5500f5f640af0afb9a23f",
        "functie": "lichtkrant Vredenburg",
        "__v": 0,
        "discipline": "5ddd10629ce8a5255458cf9b"
      }
    ],
    "regionaam": [
      {
        "_id": "5dd5645d9c432c413ce3cfc1",
        "naam": "Gelderland Midden"
      }
    ],
    "DisciplineNaam": [
      {
        "_id": "5ddd10629ce8a5255458cf9b",
        "afkorting": "BRW",
        "naam": "Brandweer",
        "meldingBenaming": "BRAN",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5ddd10629ce8a5255458cc9b",
        "afkorting": "AMBU",
        "naam": "Ambulance",
        "meldingBenaming": "AMBU",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ],
    "gkprNaam": [
      {
        "_id": "5dd5500f5f640af0afb9a23a",
        "naam": "Arnhem"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5dd5500f5f640af0afb9a23f",
        "naam": "Arnhem Vredenburg"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But this is what I'm looking for...
[image: This is what I want]

I have such an idea that I can best solve this with the $project function of Mongo but I would not know how ... Thanks in advance!

Database Structure
[image: Database Structure]

*Edited 12:59am*

Hmm, I found a way that might help. A $concat feature from MongoDB.. But I can't get it working

Comment: Confirm please if you are using MongoDB >=v3.6

Comment: Using MongoDB Version: 4.2.3 :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Meldingen.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "capcodes",
      let: {
        capcodes: "$capcodes"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$_id",
                "$$capcodes"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "regios",
            "localField": "regio",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "regionaam"
          }
        },
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "disciplines",
            "localField": "discipline",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "disciplineNaam"
          }
        },
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "gpkrs",
            "localField": "gpkr",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "gkprNaam"
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: "$_id",
            regio: {
              $let: {
                vars: {
                  input: {
                    $arrayElemAt: [
                      "$regionaam",
                      0
                    ]
                  }
                },
                in: "$$input.naam"
              }
            },
            gpkr: {
              $let: {
                vars: {
                  input: {
                    $arrayElemAt: [
                      "$gkprNaam",
                      0
                    ]
                  }
                },
                in: "$$input.naam"
              }
            },
            discipline: {
              $let: {
                vars: {
                  input: {
                    $arrayElemAt: [
                      "$disciplineNaam",
                      0
                    ]
                  }
                },
                in: "$$input.naam"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "capcodes"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      tijd: 1,
      melding: 1,
      capcodes: 1
    }
  }
]).exec(function (err, docs) {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(docs);
});
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/asckIrzG2Jw)

Comment: If I want to add two extra fields from the table of 'Disciplines', where do I need to define them? It concerns 'Afkorting' and 'meldingbenaming' rows. See the image with the database structure.

Comment: @Simon You mean [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WPnQkp-tPPR)?